# Mysql How to count all stages of a particular employee's production within a month

Tags: mysql

I would like to retrieve from the database the data on the number of steps taken by employees divided into all days of the month.

I have  table: production_control

```
CREATE TABLE `production_control` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `internal` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `employee` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `step` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `production_control` (`id`, `internal`, `employee`, `step`, `date`) VALUES
(1, '546892986', 'E.DF', 'step1', '2017-09-27 14:14:11'),
(2, '177433986', 'E.EN', 'Montażysta', '2017-09-28 08:51:50'),
(3, '953892986', 'E.DF', 'step2', '2017-09-28 09:10:22'),
(4, '170005359', 'E.DF', 'step2', '2017-09-28 08:33:10'),
(5, '135099059', 'E.DF', 'step1', '2017-09-29 14:16:28')
```

And I would like to get such data:

```
employee| step  |  date      | count
E.DF    | step1 | 2017-09-27 | 1
E.DF    | step2 | 2017-09-28 | 2
E.DF    | step1 | 2017-09-29 | 1
```

Is it possible to extract these data in a single query?
And is it possible to insert in the zero result for a given day of the month in which the employee did not complete the production step?

```
E.DF    | step1 | 2017-09-20 | 0
```

Comment: (Obviously) don't store 'step'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, "Is it possible to extract these data in a single query?", yes you can.

```
SELECT employee, step, date(date), count(*)
FROM production_control
GROUP BY employee, step, date(date)
```

Your second question requires a bit more complicated approach, of which there are several. I don't have access to a mysql instance at the moment to attempt writing an answer for that question. One idea is to take the approach of having a calendar table with every possible date in it. Then left join your production control table to the calendar table. There is another way to do it with some recursive joins but the calendar table is the easiest.

Comment: Or maybe Create a temporary table and fill it with dates for that month. And later send query?I just do not know how it is with the performance of operations on temporary tables